# Use vhdx backup file as Virtual Machine in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-8, backup, hyper-v, windows-backup, vhd

I have a Windows 8 machine which I backed-up using the *Control Panel -> Windows 7 File Recovery -> Create System Image*. This produces a folder with a lot of `.xml` and a 2 `.vhdx` files. Is it possible to use the `.vhdx` files as a Virtual Machine in the Hyper-V Manager in Windows 8 Pro? If so, how?

Comment: If you continue to use original system AND have it's image as a virtual machine, you are most likely going against license agreement, so watch out.

Comment: Yes I know, but this is a different license. Its from a laptop.

Comment: But isn't the laptop also in use? The point Kitet was trying to make is that each copy of Windows, whether physical or virtual, requires a separate license.

Comment: Yes, the laptop is still in use. Maybe its not to smart then.